# Unable to see commands in selenium IDE 2.9.1

Tags: selenium-ide

I am using selenium IDE 2.9.1. I'm opening Test case recorded earlier for making changes in it, but I'm unable to see the commands in the Table view though I can see the HTML code in the source view.

Can you guide and suggest me how to view the earlier recorded scripts?

Comment: I tried recording a script in V 2.9.1, saving it, creating a new script, loading the previous script and it shows as expected in Table View and Source View. Are you trying to load scripts written in a previous version? Were the scripts modified in some way outside of Selenium IDE? Is there something else you are doing/not doing that can add clarity to your question? What other things have you tried to resolve the issue?